# Some query help - SQL passes validation but returns no records

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automationstudio, sql

Admittedly, I'm not an expert in SQL. Below is code I wrote to pull all clicks for a specific subscriber and nothing is coming back. I tried adding a date criteria to limit the search to 6 months, because perhaps the query is timing out.

**Here is the query:**

```sql
SELECT
    a.SubscriberKey,
    a.URL,
    a.EventDate,
    b.EmailName,
    a.JobID
FROM _Click a
JOIN _Job b
    ON a.JobID = b.JobID
WHERE
    SubscriberKey = 'abc@xyz.com' AND
    EventDate > DateAdd(d,-180,GetDate())
```

Does anything jump out as a miss in my SQL?

Comment: Try swapping your event date condition for DateDiff(d,eventdate,getdate) < 180

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the target data extension?

Comment: I think the issue is with the fact that when you job and click have a one to many relationship i.e. One job maps to many clicks.

Comment: Are you running it from an Automation?  If not, you should.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the target DE.  I should add that I know data exists, because the user shows clicks when viewed in All Subscribers "History" tab.

[![target DE][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw7hf.png  [1]][1]]

Comment: if the query is timing out then it would fail. Is it failing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are comparing the number field type comparisons, they need to be converted to an integer in order to do a correct equal comparison, I came across the same problem in a query I ran earlier.

```
SELECT
    a.SubscriberKey,
    a.URL,
    a.EventDate,
    b.EmailName,
    a.JobID
FROM _Click a
JOIN _Job b
    ON CONVERT(INT, a.JobID) = CONVERT(INT, b.JobID)
WHERE
    SubscriberKey = 'abc@xyz.com' AND
    EventDate > DateAdd(d,-180,GetDate())
```

I have not tested it, but let me know if this works.